# String value in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I am working on a SQL Server stored procedure to export a file in `.csv` format, in which there is conditional statement given below:

```
xp_cmdshell  ' bcp 
"Select ''Status'' union all Select (CASE WHEN (foo.new_value != '' ) THEN  ''Start'' ELSE ''Stop'' END)
from table_name as foo"
queryout c:/test.csv -T -c -t'
```

When I run the above query it's not exporting any file on executing the procedure. I think the problem occurs due to string `Start` and `Stop` values because when I execute a query mentioned below, it's executing perfectly fine and successfully export file with name `test.csv`.

```
xp_cmdshell  ' bcp 
"Select ''Status'' union all Select foo.new_value from table_name as foo" 
queryout c:/test.csv -T -c -t'
```

So here is my question how can I insert string value which replace `new_value` column value with `"Start"` or `"Stop"` values.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the problem just the case statement where you haven't escaped `'` properly, since the result of your string is:

```
... CASE WHEN (foo.new_value != ' ) THEN
```

So you should add 2 more `'`s:

```
... CASE WHEN (foo.new_value != '''') THEN
```